# Android app which only have a service starts in the background can't receive broadcast message

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm having a problem about android BroadcastReceiver. It's the first time for asking questions on stack overflow, and my English is bad. So I describe the question in Chinese again in the end!

I want my app can automatic run when the android system starts.First I register a BroadcasetReceiver which can receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` message in the static way (in the `AndroidManifest.xml`).This BroadcastReceiver works well. The BroadcastReceiver needs to start a service, the service is running all the time, and it registers another BroadcastReceiver which can receive the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` message in the dynamic way.But when the networks changes, the app can't receive the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` message in the `HUAWEI` pad only when the app starts the main Activity.(It can works well in the `HUAWEI` phone).

note：The BroadcastReceiver which receives the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` message must be register in the dynamic way. Because the app need to unregister it sometimes.

(写了一个开机自动启动的程序，开机启动一个service，这个service一启动就动态的注册一个监听网络变化的broadcastreceiver，可是在华为的pad上，这个broadcastreceiver始终不能接收到网络状态变化的广播消息，除非启动主Activity，但是华为手机没有这个问题！)

Answer (score 0):

1、Your phone's Android version maybe not same to your pad's;
2、I suggest you register broadcast in static way;
3、Are you sure this service started after reboot? you can write a log .